# CD backward to named folder

Tags: linux, bash

Was wondering if there exists any *nix command (or script) that allows me change directories backward to a folder matching a certain name.

For instance, pretend `pwd` is:

> ~/workspace/proj/subproj/src/main/java

I want to type something like:

`cd ..proj` and instantly be cd'd back to the `proj` folder. (instead of having to type `cd ../../../../`)

P.S. Having Autocomplete, such that I could do: `cd ..pr<tab>` would be awesome as well.

Comment: You can go back to the last pwd directory by using cd - . Maybe this helps at least a little bit.

Comment: There is no such thing in Bash. But, your friendly Bash built-ins, `pushd`, `popd` and `dirs` can help you a bit. Instead of `cd`, change directory with `pushd` and then later on recall wanted directory with `pushd +<num>` which rotates the stack (`dirs` outputs directory stack for you). To remove directories from the stack, use `popd`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not as such no, but here are some useful tricks.

1. Use `cd -`. This will move you to your previous directory.
2. Use `pushd`:

   ```
   $ pushd foo/bar/baz/foobar/babar/
   /home/terdon/foo/bar/baz/foobar/babar
   ~/foo/bar/baz/foobar/babar ~
   $ pwd
   /home/terdon/foo/bar/baz/foobar/babar
   $ pushd ~/foo/
   ~/foo ~/foo/bar/baz/foobar/babar ~
   $ pushd +1
   ~/foo/bar/baz/foobar/babar ~ ~/foo
   $ pwd
   /home/terdon/foo/bar/baz/foobar/babar
   ```
3. Use the `CDPATH` variable. This allows you to use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to autocomplete directory names from anywhere as long as those directories are defined in `CDPATH`. For example, say I have a directory named `~/foo` with 4 subdirectories:

   ```
   $ tree
   .
   ├── dir1
   ├── dir2
   ├── dir3
   └── dir4
   ```

   Now, if I am in the `~/` directory, typing `dir` and <kbd>Tab</kbd> will not autocomplete to them because they are under `~/foo`. But it will if I add `~/foo` to `CDPATH`:

   ```
   $ CDPATH="~/foo"
   $ cd dir ## Hit tab here
   dir/   dir1/  dir2/  dir3/  dir4/
   ```
4. Use a function that searches the parent directories for where you want to go. Just add these lines to your `~/.bashrc` and then run `source ~/.bashrc` or just open a new terminal:

   ```
   find_target(){
       ## The target directory
       _target=$1
       ## Iterate through the parent directories
       printf "%s\n" "$PWD" | sed -r 's#/#/\n#g' |
       while read parent_dir; 
       do
           ## Check if the target directory exists under this
           ## parent directory and if it does, print the
           ## target's path and break the loop.
           _path="${_path}${parent_dir}"
           [ -d "${_path}${_target}" ] && echo "${_path}${_target}" && break
       done
   }

   ## If the value passed as an argument to
   ## this function exists as a subdirectory of
   ## any of the current directory's parents, 
   ## cd into it. Else, fail silently.
   pcd(){
       cd "$(find_target $1)" 2>/dev/null
   }
   ```

   You will now be able to run `pcd baz` and you will be moved to `../../../baz`. The function will find the 1st directory named `baz` that is a subdirectory of any of your current directories.

   CAVEATS:

   1. It will not check for subdirectories recursively. For example, if you are in `~/foo/bar/baz/`, `pcd foo` will move you to `../../foo` but it will not find `../bar/foo` if such a directory exists.
   2. It will move to the 1st directory found (the one furthest up).

Comment: I like your #4.  I was thinking of something similar.  One could work around the caveats if they wanted to put in the effort.  Heck, one could move further *up* the tree too if they wanted to put in even some more effort.

Comment: @Keltari sure, you could use `find` instead or all sorts of tricks. Just not worth it unless the OP specifies exactly what they need. Ideally, you would be presented with choices between `../foo/baz` and `../../baz` etc. That's more effort than I'm willing to expend right now though :)

Comment: @terdon #4 is perfect, just what I want actually.